# Remote http archetypeCatalog doesn't work in Linux

Tags: linux, maven, catalog, maven-archetype

I created one Maven archetype and uploaded to Nexus repository. I can generate one project based on that archetype with "mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://myhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/my-snapshots/archetype-catalog.xml " command on Windows. The catalog xml is valid and I can open from browser manually.

Now I followed the same steps on Linux, configured the server part and repository profile in conf/setting.xml as the same content with Windows. The maven reported "No catalog defined. Using internal catalog". It seems the Maven didn't read the "-DarchetypeCatalog=...." part.

The debug log is as below. Maven version is 3.3.9. The issue reproduced on both Redhat and Ubuntu. Hope anyone can suggest a solution. Thanks.

```
[DEBUG] RuntimeInstance successfully initialized.
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) archetypeCatalog = http://myhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/my-snapshots/archetype-catalog.xml 
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = /opt/testmaven
[DEBUG]   (f) interactiveMode = true
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///root/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) remoteArtifactRepositories = [      id: my-snapshots
      url: http://myhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/my-snapshots
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => false, update => always]
,       id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@4943defe
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No catalog defined. Using internal catalog
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-archetype (An archetype which contains a sample archetype.)
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings.xml, we need to configure a mirror :

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <name>Local Nexus Mirror</name>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://myhost:8080/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Once you’ve configured Nexus to be the mirror for all repositories, Maven will now consult the local installation of Nexus instead of going out to the central Maven repository.

If Nexus has the artifact requested, the artifact will be served from the local Nexus installation.

We can try specifying `-DarchetypeCatalog=remote` or `-DarchetypeCatalog=local` while generating the maven artifact through `mvn archetype:generate`.

If the archetype-cataog is available in local, we can directly use `-Dcatalog=<url>`